# LuaPlus: How to make a function return a table?

Tags: c++, function, lua, lua-table, luaplus

I'm wondering how I you can create and register a function from the C++-side that returns a table when called from the Lua-side.
I've tried a lot of things but nothing did really work. :/

(sorry for the long code)
This for example won't work, because Register() expects a "luaCFunction"-styled function:

```
LuaPlus::LuaObject Test( LuaPlus::LuaState* state ) {
    int top = state->GetTop();
    std::string var( state->ToString(1) );

    LuaPlus::LuaObject tableObj(state);
    tableObj.AssignNewTable(state);

    if (var == "aaa")
        tableObj.SetString("x", "ABC");
    else if (var == "bbb")
        tableObj.SetString("x", "DEF");
    tableObj.SetString("y", "XYZ");
    return tableObj;
}
int main()
{
    LuaPlus::LuaState* L = LuaPlus::LuaState::Create(true);
     //without true I can't access the standard libraries like "math.","string."...
     //with true, GetLastError returns 2 though (ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
     //no side effects noticed though

    LuaPlus::LuaObject globals = L->GetGlobals();

    globals.Register("Test",Test);

    char pPath[MAX_PATH];
    GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH,pPath);
    strcat_s(pPath,MAX_PATH,"\\test.lua");
    if(L->DoFile(pPath)) {
        if( L->GetTop() == 1 ) // An error occured
            std::cout << "An error occured: " << L->CheckString(1) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

When I try to set it up as a luaCFunction-function it just crashes (0x3) and says:
*Assertion failed: 0, file C:\......\[luafunction.h](http://pastebin.com/Pmwq8E0p), line 41*

```
int Test( LuaPlus::LuaState* state ) {
    int top = state->GetTop();
    std::string var( state->ToString(1) );

    LuaPlus::LuaObject tableObj(state);
    tableObj.AssignNewTable(state);

    if (var == "aaa")
        tableObj.SetString("x", "ABC");
    else if (var == "bbb")
        tableObj.SetString("x", "DEF");
    tableObj.SetString("y", "XYZ");

    tableObj.Push();

    return state->GetTop() - top;
}
```

For clarification: from the Lua side I wanted it to be callable like:

```
myVar = Test("aaa")
Print(myVar) -- output: ABC
```

**EDIT: The Print function comes from [here](http://www.zynox.net/luaplus-1-compiling-basic-usage/). And was basically the cause for this to not work. Print can only print strings not tables... The C++ code from above works fine if you just return 1.**

This is the documentation that came with my LuaPlus version btw: http://luaplus.funpic.de/

I really hope you can help me.. I'm already starting to think that it is not possible. :'(

**edit:**
I totally forgot to say that using PushStack() lead into an error because "the member does not exist"...

Comment: What happens if you replace `return state->GetTop() - top;` with `return 1;`? (In the last line of the `Test` function) and what does `errorString` contain?

Comment: Yes, I get the same error.

Comment: How are you calling the test script from C++?

Comment: Yes, I try to put the important parts together: http://pastebin.com/Ccd93DPQ I'll put it in the question now too.

Comment: Did you already try narrowing down the problem by eliminating variables? eg. trying `L->DoFile("test.lua")`, putting test.lua in the same working directory etc. Can you get a stacktrace when the assert fails?

Comment: Note I don't mean *variables* in the programming sense but external possible factors.

Comment: The file runs fine. But as soon as Test() is called it stops gives me this error message and crashes with 0x3. I checked "top" and "state->ToString(1)" in the beginning and in the end of the function: top was always 1 state->ToString(1) was always "aaa" (the parameter I passed).

Comment: Have you tried the LuaPlusCallback wrapped Register version? The managed example from http://luaplus.funpic.de/#table8?

Comment: If you are building LuaPlus yourself you could try logging/printing/etc. the errorString on line 40 in luafunction.h instead of just throwing it away as is currently happening.

Comment: I tried the callback function and it gave me a lot of errors: http://250kb.de/u/131111/j/Nluz4tKZfkAF.jpg ... I don't really understand what you mean by logging the errorString? I mean, it's already printing this error. The problem is that I don't know what it means or better what I'd have to do to avoid it. :/

Comment: LuaPlus is getting the error from the lua_pcall and then doing absolutely nothing with it. It is then failing an assertion which gives no additional information. That errorString variable (unless it is being used somewhere magically that I didn't see) might very well contain useful information.

Comment: @Forivin Sorry I was busy the last few days; Again, please tell us the contents of `errorString` (http://pastebin.com/Pmwq8E0p Line 40, and others); Set a breakpoint for assertion in your debugger, and inspect the local variable. If the library is compiled with optimizations this may not exist though. So you could inspect the top of the Lua stack, since the error message will still be there.

Comment: @Forivin Can you upload your complete example project somewhere and add a link to it in your question? There's clearly a subtle issue happening that isn't being captured in your question.

Comment: Oh man, I just checked the errorString and was able to fix the problem. For some reason the test.lua file didn't update anymore when I compiled the solution. So while I thought the content would be "print(Test("aaa").x)" it was actually "print(Test("aaa"))". -.- I feel so stupid... I totally misunderstood you dualed, when you first asked me for the contents of "errorString". Well, add it as an answer and I will accept it. Thank you so much for all your help everyone.

Comment: @Forivin Make sure to do this soon otherwise the bounty will just disappear into the ether. :(

Comment: I'm confused. What was in errorString? I don't understand the solution either. Was the problem when trying to print the returned table somehow?

Comment: The solution was to use the code from my question (the second one of course) and just return 1. It didn't work, because I made a mistake in the test.lua script. The luascript was trying to print the table instead of an index of the table. That's what caused all this.. So basically I'm super stupid and I'm sorry for it. :)  
@greatwolf I think I can't because he posted it as a comment and not as an answer.

Comment: Attempting to print a table should absolutely not crash. Something is still very wrong if that is happening. And returning 1 shouldn't be any different than the `gettop() - top` version assuming that you only push one element on the stack. If you push more than that then it is obviously going to be different since it will return more things.

Comment: I also still want to know what was in errorString exactly.

Comment: I'm also wondering the same thing as @EtanReisner. `L->DoFile` just calls `luaL_dofile` which uses `lua_pcall`. If there *was* an issue with your test script why didn't `if(L->DoFile(pPath))` catch and print the error?

Comment: Sorry. I didnt used the original "print" function I used the "Print" function. It comes from this tutorial: http://www.zynox.net/luaplus-1-compiling-basic-usage/ and it can't handle tables. The errorString contained: "....\test.lua:1 bad argument #1 to 'Print' (string expected, got table)" I really don't know why this wasn't catched by L->DoFile. I guess DoFile just returns false if the file does not exist or so..

Comment: The error was being caught by the pcall. That's why you had that error in errorString. The problem is that LuaPlus in that function takes the error string throws it away and then generates an entirely context-less assertion instead. That's marvelously stupid and unhelpful.

Comment: Unfortunately the end result of all of this mess is that I think the question, as written and asked, is entirely incorrect and ultimately unhelpful for anyone else. I don't know what SO guidelines are about that but I would probably suggest retracting the question or, at very least, editing it to include the actual lua script being run and the Print function involved.

Comment: True. :/ I will put the wrong luascipt in the question then..

Comment: Letting a bounty expire like this would be criminal so I added an answer just before it ended. @Forivin Let me know if anything below is unclear.

Comment: @Forivin Any chance for you to award the bounty to my answer? The grace period is ending soon and it would really suck for the rep to just disappear into the void. If you still have any related concerns, I'll do my best to address them.

Comment: oO I already marked your answer as the accepted one. Did I miss anyhting? Do I have to do something else? Edit: I just found out that I had to click the +100 button. sorry :p

Comment: yeah, it's kind of annoying that way. Since it's the grace period, you have to manually award the bounty :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some painstaking probing from the long comment discussion, I'm posting this answer to help summary the situation and hopefully to offer some useful advice.

The main issue the OP was running into was that the wrong `print` function was being called in the lua test script. Contrary to the original code shown the real code the OP was testing against was calling *`Print(myVar)`* which is a custom provided lua_CFunction and not the builtin `print` function.

Somehow along the way, this ended up creating some instantiation of `template <typename RT> class LuaFunction` and calling the overloaded `operator()()`. From inspecting the `luafunction.h` from luaPlus any lua errors that occurs inside this call will get swallowed up without any kind of logging (not a good design decision on luaPlus's part):

```
  if (lua_pcall(L, 0, 1, 0)) {
      const char* errorString = lua_tostring(L, -1);  (void)errorString;
      luaplus_assert(0);
  }
```

To help catch future errors like this, I suggest adding a new `luaplus_assertlog` macro. Specifically, this macro will *include* the `errorString` so that the context isn't completely lost and hopefully help with debugging. This change *hopefully* won't break existing uses of `luaplua_assert` from other parts of the API. In the long run though, it's probably better to modify `luaplus_assert` so it actually includes *something meaningful*.

Anyway here's a diff of the changes made:

**LuaPlusInternal.h**

```
@@ -81,5 +81,6 @@
 } // namespace LuaPlus

 #if !LUAPLUS_EXCEPTIONS
+#include <stdio.h>
 #include <assert.h>
 #define luaplus_assert(e) if (!(e)) assert(0)
@@ -84,5 +85,6 @@
 #include <assert.h>
 #define luaplus_assert(e) if (!(e)) assert(0)
+#define luaplus_assertlog(e, msg) if (!(e)) { fprintf(stderr, msg); assert(0); }
 //(void)0
 #define luaplus_throw(e) assert(0)
 //(void)0
```

**LuaFunction.h**

```
@@ -21,7 +21,7 @@
 class LuaFunction
 {
 public:
-   LuaFunction(LuaObject& _functionObj)
+   LuaFunction(const LuaObject& _functionObj)
    : functionObj(_functionObj) {
  }

@@ -36,7 +36,7 @@

    if (lua_pcall(L, 0, 1, 0)) {
      const char* errorString = lua_tostring(L, -1);  (void)errorString;
-           luaplus_assert(0);
+           luaplus_assertlog(0, errorString);
    }
    return LPCD::Type<RT>::Get(L, -1);
  }
```

In the change above, I opted not to use `std::cerr` simply because C++ streams tend to be heavier than plain-old C-style io functions. This is especially true if you're using mingw as your toolchain -- the `ld` linker is unable to eliminate unused C++ stream symbols even if your program never uses it.

With that in place, here's an example where an unprotected call is made to a lua function so you can see the `errorString` printed out prior to the crash:

```
// snip...
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    LuaStateAuto L ( LuaState::Create(true) );
    LuaObject globals = L->GetGlobals();
    globals.Register("Test", Test);
    globals.Register("Print", Print);
    if(argc > 1)
    {
      /*
      if (L->DoFile(argv[argc - 1]))
        std::cout << L->CheckString(1) << '\n';
      /*/
      L->LoadFile( argv[argc - 1] );
      LuaFunction<int> f ( LuaObject (L, -1) );
      f();
      //*/
    }
}
```

Running the above will trigger the crash but will include a semi-helpful error message:

```
g++ -Wall -pedantic -O0 -g   -I ./Src -I ./Src/LuaPlus/lua51-luaplus/src plustest.cpp -o plustest.exe lua51-luaplus.dll

plustest.exe plustest.lua
plustest.lua:2: bad argument #1 to 'Print' (string expected, got table)Assertion failed!

Program: G:\OSS\luaplus51-all\plustest.exe
File: ./Src/LuaPlus/LuaFunction.h, Line 39

Expression: 0

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

Answer (score 1):

first you may try to register the function using RegisterDirect(), this may avoid lua_CFunction's problem, check the luaplus manual.like this

```
LuaPlus::LuaObject globals = L->GetGlobals();

globals.RegisterDirect("Test",Test);
```

second if I remeber to create a table have two solutions,like this

```
//first
LuaObject globalsObj = state->GetGlobals();  
LuaObject myArrayOfStuffTableObj = globalsObj.CreateTable("MyArrayOfStuff"); 

//second
LuaObject aStandaloneTableObj;  
aStandaloneTableObj.AssignNewTable(state);
```

check whether you have use the right function.

third I remember the lua stack object is not the luaobject, they have a conversion, may be you can try this

```
LuaStackObject stack1Obj(state, 1);
LuaObject nonStack1Obj = stack1Obj;
```

forth, like the function Test() you have give above, the table tableObj you have pushing onto the lua stack, you must remember to clear the object.